# How to avoid re mounting react comp item of a list when list size change?

Tags: reactjs, list, redux, rendering

I have a list of item. Data are stored in redux. Each item does fetch data (http call), on item component did mount.
In each item I can delete this item.

My problem is when I delete one item, the list re render (because size change), re mounting each item, making each item do a new http call.

Is there any way to prevent re mounting ?

Comment: Could you please share what you have tried on code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't need to use `React.Memo` or `React.PureComponent` for this. Components shouldn't get unmounted when they're in a list that other items are removed from, if that's happening it suggests that your problem lies in the way your list is managed and updated.

[Here's a quick code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-water-s4rjn) that demonstrates this - I've added a `console.log` to `componentDidMount` for each item, if you open the console you can see that it only gets called once by each item on start-up. When you remove items, the others stay mounted.

Answer (score 1):

Use `React.Memo` or `React.PureComponent` to perform a shallow comparison in child's props and only re-render when `props` actually changes

Comment: Nope. It does not work because the list item is re-render, so each item is re mounting. Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

For your Usecase, KEYS are the best feature from REACT which you can relay upon.

Ref this :

https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html#keys

https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys